# How to find the NEGOTIATED cipher suite for a new connection

Tags: security, jetty, embedded-jetty

In an attempt to further increase security for an embedded web server app based on Jetty 9.3/JRE8 build 45 I want to limit my server to ONLY service TLS 1.2 (or future 1.2 and 1.3) and only these cipher suites :

0xC0,0x2B   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 Y   [RFC5289]

0xC0,0x2C   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 Y   [RFC5289]

However, in order to allow user agents for which a fall-back cipher suite has been negotiated to end up in my server's handle() function where Jetty hands the thread over to me, I need to allow for some other cipher suites to pass, otherwise I cannot send back a simple HTML page asking the user to get a suitable browser.

All that has been properly set-up with the sslContextFactory object and works fine when I test the concept with cipher suites that I have support for TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

I am not sure why my two preferred ones above don't work yet. Must be an ECDSA problem because my Goolge Chrome has TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 as preferred suite too according this site: cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de

However, once in my handle() method I need to be able to find out if one of the above cipher suits were elected or not, so that in the case of NOT I can inform the user he needs a browser supporting TLS 1.2 and Elliptic Curve on its own like FireFox or in combination with an EC enabled OS as requires Chrome (e.g. Windows as of Vista) etc.

I checked the HTTP/1.1 RFC and hoped that the 'Connection' or 'Upgrade' HTTP tag would hold something useful. I also searched for other HTTP header names that could hold the negotiated cipher suite.

I then look into some related RFC for HTTP over TLS in the hopes that maybe there was a way to ask some header rewriting to include a tag with the cipher suite. I have also look if there was some method on the servlet request object that would disclose the cipher suite but the closest was the more generic isSecure() or the getScheme() (http/https). I also enumerate all header names and associated values to see if there was something there.

Finally I found a link from Microsoft explaining how to extract that information from the [TLS record](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299520) but then I realized that information is no longer available when my handle() method is called by Jetty.

I know that TCP/IP and TLS 1.2 is handled before Jetty gets the connection. So the cipher suite might not be available, just like a TCP/IP accept cannot be prevent early (without connect/disconnect) from inside the handle() method.

But maybe someone knows a way to get the cipher suite or could end my search by saying it is not possible.

The general philosophy here is that I will only service HTTPS TLS 1.2/HTTP 2.0 with the above cipher suites and HSTS + redirecting all HTTP to HTTPS but that I always need to allow OTHER UNWANTED connections to come to my handle() method to send back a basic HTML page to ask for a browser upgrade. So it is in my handle() that I need to find out what I am dealing with on a connection per connection base. The cipher suite is the last peace I need.

So ALTERNATIVELY could there be a way to set a message that will be send back to the User Agent (HTML) if I would close the door by only accepting both above cipher suites with the setIncludeCipherSuits() of the sslContextFactory. The user would then see that message instead of the default error the browser displays based on the failed cipher suite negotiations by lack of common cipher suite support.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `ServerConnector` with an `HttpConfiguration` that has the `SecureRequestCustomizer` enabled, then you can do this ...

```java
String cipherSuite = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite");
```

That will return the name of the cipher suite in use by the [`SSLSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html) on the established secure connection.

Comment: I do indeed use ServerConnector the way you describe. Your suggestion works 100%, thanks.